# Setting Class Properties

Tags: php

I am adding classes to some legacy code and wondering if there is a more appropriate way to be setting the properties. I am also trying to understand the trade offs, if there is another way to do this.
I'm trying to find out if there is a better way to do this? If there is, why? If there isn't, why is this better than the alternative?

```
class Foo
{   
    public $id;

    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->id   = $id;
        $this->getDetails();
    }

    /**
     *
     * Assigns all properties
     *
     */
    public function getDetails()
    {
        $db = Database::getDatabase();

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM foos WHERE id = '{$this->id}' ";
        $result = $db->getRow($sql);

        foreach($result as $key => $value) {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Security**

Use prepared statements. Classes are reusable, so even if the id is not user provided *right now*, this may very well change in the future, making your code vulnerable to SQL injection.

**Naming**

`getDetails` is rather vague. What details? Additionally, `getX` usually signals that the method returns X, which isn't the case here.

Your comment is a bit better, something like `assignProperties` might work. I would prefer something like `loadById`, `populateById`, or more explicit `populateFieldsById`.

**General Structur**

`getDetails` should be private, right?

As for the general structure, it's fine.

I would probably separate the `Foo` object from the code retrieving it from the database like this (pseudo code):

```
// just setters, getters, and business logic
class Foo {

    constructor(...) {...}
    getPropertyX() {...}
    setPropertyX(...) {...}
    getPropertyY() {...}
    setPropertyY(...) {...}
    performSomeBusinesslogicOnObject() {...}

}

// performing database interactions and populating Foo objects
class FooDAO {

    Foo getById(id) {...}
    Foo getByPropertyZ(z) {...}
    save(Foo foo) {...}

}
```

My main reason for doing it this way is that it separates the database operation from the model.

Now, you can use the model without being forced to have a database interaction (maybe one isn't needed right now, maybe you want to run tests, maybe the current instance of the object comes from somewhere else than the database, etc).

On the other hand, if most of your business logic happens directly on the database, not the object, this might get confusing. So it really also depends on what `Foo` is exactly. But for simple objects which are mainly retrieved, updated, saved, etc, this is the way I would go.